# How can I detect a click on the cancel "x" in the input type search?

Tags: angular, input

I have a search input type in my angular web app.

```
<div class="input-group mb-4">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (keydown.enter)="search($event.target.value)" (cancel)="onCancelSearch()" >
      </div>
```

An "x" appears when a search term is entered. I want to detect click on that "x". I have tried

```
(cancel)="onCancelSearch()"
```

But this did not work for me. How can I detect a click on the cancel?

Comment: From where this "x" is coming from? Are you using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: @GabrielMartins It's provided by the 'search' input element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search

Comment: You can probably use the onchange event to detect when the value is of zero length, thereby knowing the search has been cancelled. But I haven't tried this

Comment: @GabrielMartins The "x" is part of the standard search input type.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to trigger a function call on search using ngModelChange like so,

```
<input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" (ngModelChange) = "search()">
```

Inside the search function, I was able to check the searchTerm and detect if it was cleared or not.

Comment: that is correct  but ngModelChange will trigger on every change like while you enter `a,ab,abc ` you may need to be careful in case you send  http request